# Rails 3: Jquery Autocomplete for Users to link to '/user/#'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently trying to get the rails gem 'https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete' to link to user profiles through the click of the username on the dropdown. My current form is listed below and I cannot figure how take the parameter for :id to not send me to the URL

```
/users/id?utf8=✓&user[username]=arinh&user[id]=
```

I tried without get method and it just does the URL /users/id

I have tried saving the :id as a html5 element as show in the github but I couldn't get that to work either. I'm stuck.

Very new to rails, any help counts.

```
      <%= form_for (:user), :url => user_path(:id), html: { class: 'navbar-form' }, :method => :get  do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
      <div class="input-group" style="padding: 0 35px;">
        <%= f.autocomplete_field :username, autocomplete_user_username_users_path, :class => 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
          <% end %>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#user_username').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
          window.location.href = '/users/' + data.item.id;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Finally found my answer.